# Programmatically define jta datasource using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to define a JTA datasource programmatically using hibernate. I tried searching it on google but could not find any feasible solution. Does any know How can I defined JTA DS programmatically.

Comment: I got it working by creating a class that uses PersistenceUnitInfo